# need explanation of vDSP_zcoher()

Tags: ios, signal-processing, core-audio, accelerate-framework, vdsp

im currently working with raw audio data and to compare two pieces of signal i came across [vDSP_zcoher()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009464-CH15-BBCHJHJI) and i have several questions about that:

1. why is the output a complex array and not real. i expected a real array just like the output of a correlation for example. **Update:** seems to be wrong in the docu, D is real.
2. Are the parameters A,B and C accumulating auto- and cross spectra created with [vDSP_zaspec](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009464-CH15-BBCEFJEJ)(A,B) and [vDSP_zcspec](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009464-CH15-BBCGCDCF)(C)?
3. am i right that the result should indicate how similar the signals are?

general explanation of the function is appreciated as well!

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. D is real, not complex. The documentation that describes __vDSP_D as “Complex output vector” is wrong. The documentation that shows the declaration “float *__vDSP_D” is correct.
2. D is not an input, so it would generally not contain output of `vDSP_zaspec` or `vDSP_zcspec`.

Otherwise, I cannot speak to how the functions are used, sorry, I do not have a background in signal-processing theory.

Comment: thanks for the help, you are right, D is listed as real but described as complex.